# Логирование всех ошибок скрипта

Tags: php

Нужно при возникновении ошибки записывать ее в БД, возможно есть библиотека, с помощью которой можно отлавливать эти ошибки ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи функции [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php) вы можете задать свой обработчик и делать там с ошибками всё что угодно.